# How to let the page stay in the current template after refresh?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, frontend

I'm using (meteor) multiple templates in one HTML file. My problem is that the webpage will change to the default template once I refresh the page regardless of which template I was in. Any solutions on this issue?

Comment: please show some sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want something like [FlowRouter](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router)

Comment: Will look into that. Thanks for the help.